# Selecting unique values that are smaller than specific values in another column

Tags: sql, sql-server, window-functions

Using a plain query, not a script, How do I achieve the following:

I have a calculated table that contains response timestamps and request timestamps.
There is no way to connect between them, except for these time stamps.

For example:

```
 Response | response_timestamp       | requests_timestamps

 X          2021-03-07 07:34:59.000    2021-03-07 07:31:16.960
 X          2021-03-07 07:34:59.000    2021-03-07 05:56:30.553
 X          2021-03-07 07:34:59.000    2021-03-07 05:55:50.623
 X          2021-03-07 07:34:59.000    2021-03-07 05:55:31.480
 Y          2021-04-06 20:02:59.000    2021-04-05 20:01:49.960
 Y          2021-04-06 20:02:59.000    2021-04-05 20:01:07.063
 Y          2021-04-06 20:02:59.000    2021-04-05 20:00:16.600
 Y          2021-04-06 20:02:59.000    2021-04-05 11:34:36.030
 Z          2021-04-06 20:01:59.000    2021-04-05 20:01:49.960
 Z          2021-04-06 20:01:59.000    2021-04-05 20:01:07.063
 Z          2021-04-06 20:01:59.000    2021-04-05 20:00:16.600
 Z          2021-04-06 20:01:59.000    2021-04-05 11:34:36.030
```

For X, there is no problem, I take the max request time that is smaller or equal to the response time, meaning: X -> 2021-03-07 07:31:16.960

The problem arises, for Y AND Z. Pay attention that they both have similar possible request timestamps.

So, in this case, I need to attach Y with 2021-04-05 20:01:49.960, and Z with 2021-04-05 20:01:07.063, because 2021-04-05 20:01:49.960 was already matched with Y...

Comment: How do you know that the `requests_timestamp` `2021-04-05 20:01:49.960` is shared among `Y` and `Z` and not `X` ?

Comment: No RDBMS supports "SQL"; they all have their own dialect of SQL and SQL Server's is T-SQL. Perhaps you mean ANSI-SQL? If so note that no RDBMS supports *all* of the ANSI standards and what they *have* implemented also varies from RDBMS to RDBMS. Just because it is ANSI-SQL doesn't mean it'll work on the RDBMS you are using, or the specific version of it.

Comment: "Without T-SQL, only SQL"  = **Using a plain query, not a script**
How do you know that the requests_timestamp 2021-04-05 20:01:49.960 is shared among  Y and Z and not X ?
**It may be shared by X also, but X has another max request time which is smaller then it and bigger than all others**

Answer (score 0):

The question is not 100% clear, because the data has patterns that are not described at all in the question.  If I assume the following:

1. Timestamps are unique unless *all* timestamps are duplicates between two responses.
2. The ordering for the responses is based on the alphabetic ordering of `response`.

Then, I can interpret the problem as matching the following two counts:

- Enumerate the timestamps within each response.
- Find the maximum of the enumeration for each response.  This is what needs to match above.

This is all easily handled with window functions and filtering:

```
select t.*
from (select t.*,
             max(request_seqnum) over (partition by response) as response_request_seqnum
      from (select t.*,
                   row_number() over (partition by requests_timestamps order by response) as request_seqnum,
                   row_number() over (partition by response order by requests_timestamps desc) as seqnum
            from t
           ) t
     ) t
where seqnum = response_request_seqnum
order by 1, 2, 3;
```

[Here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=502e88e19ce583c232283385c768e890) is a db<>fiddle.

Note:  If the above assumptions are not true, then I would suggest tha you ask a *new* question, providing appropriate sample data and a very clear explanation of the logic that needs to be implemented.